# File load completion check in java

Tags: java, file, javafx-2

I am working on a image browser project where I need to handle lots of image files. I have created a FlowPane and added those image files using a loop. But when it loads, it stuck for few seconds. I want to get rid of this.

I found that this problem relate with loading those files. My solution is to load all files in a synchronized way where files will load one at a time. How can I do that?

Is there any way to check if file loading and displaying complete?

Comment: have a look at multithreading. (For Gui, SwingWorker e.g.).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are loading the images in the main thread, then the UI freeze should be expected. You should load the images in a background process (i.e. one or more separate thread(s)). Before reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/threads/jfxpub-threads.htm), you can try loading the images (`javafx.scene.image.Image`) as:

```
Image x = new Image("file:///path/to/image.jpg", true);
```

...for background loading. See also the relevant property `progress` and method `cancel()` of `Image`.